# Office 2007 PIA registry entry installed indication

Tags: ms-office, vsto, windows-installer, registry, office-pia

I must install Office 2007 PIA as a prerequisite along with my Office 2007 add-in. The bootstrapper I am using requires me to specify a registry entry to be checked if prerequisite is installed or not.

Normally, various packages set `Installed` `DWORD` value to `1` in some registry path to indicate that a package is installed.

Which registry entry is used for Office 2007 PIA to indicate that the package is installed?

Comment: It can be downloaded from here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=59daebaa-bed4-4282-a28c-b864d8bfa513&displaylang=en The actual installer `o2007PIA.msi` is contained within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redist exe can be extracted to expose o2007PIA.msi.  Open it up in ORCA and examine it for a suitable resource to key off of.

I looked at this MSI and it records a bunch of COM Class ID's and very little else.  The uninstall key for Add/Remove programs will probably  be the best bread crumb.

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{5012000-1105-000-000-0000000FF1CE}

Comment: Good answer, here is the one I've used:
HKLM\Software\Classes\Installer\Products\00002105501100000000000000F01FEC